# I am not getting right violence results for images containing red velvet cake

Tags: google-cloud-vision

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI5aS.jpg)Cloud vision always returns violent label with likely for images of red velvet cake and images containing red colour.. I am using cloud vision in my application for image moderation